# Web3 error: The method eth_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available (Ropsten)

Tags: javascript, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js, metamask

I was able to call the contract, its properties and get the addresses in my html file. My dapp uses metamask and the metamask portion is working fine. However, when I attempted to call a method from the smart contract (it is similar to OpenZepplin's ERC20), the error in the title appears. Below is the relevant parts of my code (i used pure JS):

```
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(the_provider_link_which_is_correct));
    const privateKey = my_private_key
    const loginButton = document.getElementById('loginButton')
    const userWallet = document.getElementById('userWallet')

    async function loginWithMetaMask() {
      const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.error(e.message)
          return
        })
      if (!accounts) { return }
      else{
        web3.eth.defaultAccount  = accounts[0]
        console.log(web3.eth.defaultAccount)
      }
      
    }
 
    loginWithMetaMask()
    var key = prompt("What is the key?")
    console.log(key)
    var coinABI = [
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "name",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "_spender",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "name": "_value",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "approve",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "success",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "totalSupply",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "_from",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "name": "_to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "name": "_value",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "transferFrom",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "success",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "balances",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "decimals",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "allowed",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "_owner",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "balanceOf",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "balance",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "symbol",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "_to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "name": "_value",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "transfer",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "success",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "_owner",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "name": "_spender",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "allowance",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "remaining",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "_initialAmount",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "name": "_tokenName",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "_decimalUnits",
                "type": "uint8"
            },
            {
                "name": "_tokenSymbol",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "constructor"
    },
    {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "name": "_from",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "name": "_to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "name": "_value",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "Transfer",
        "type": "event"
    },
    {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "name": "_owner",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "name": "_spender",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "name": "_value",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "Approval",
        "type": "event"
    }
]



var tokenContractAddress=  token_contract_address
var tokenContract = web3.eth.contract(coinABI).at(tokenContractAddress);




// view number of tokens (this part is alright)
function viewBalance(){
  const Addr = $('#viewAddr').val();
  console.log(Addr)
  const balance =  tokenContract.balanceOf(Addr);
  console.log(balance)
  $("#balance").html(balance.c/1000);
}

// view your balance (this part is fine)
function viewCurrBalance(){
  const balance =  tokenContract.balanceOf(window.userWalletAddress );
  console.log(balance.c)
  $("#balance").html(balance.c/1000)
}

// you send to another address (THIS IS THE PROBLEM)
function sendTokens(){
  console.log()
  console.log($("#targetAddr").val())
  console.log($("#amt").val())
//   sendData(window.userWalletAddress,$("#targetAddr").val(),$("#amt").val())
  
  tokenContract.transfer($("#targetAddr").val().toString(),$("#amt").val())
}
```

Comment: What web3 provider are you using? A public third party service such as Infura? Local provider, e.g. Ganache? Custom node such as Geth? ...

Comment: im using infura (ropsten)

Comment: Btw im using pure HTML and javascript

Comment: update: i heard we need something like truffle wallet provider, but how do we put it inside pure html and javascript?